# xsl template not giving correct output to main stylesheets

Tags: xslt

In `allTemplate.xsl`

```
<xsl:template match="myRadio">
    <xsl:variable name="radioName"/>
    <input type="radio" value = "F" name="{radioName}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In `main.xsl`

```
<myRadio>
       <xsl:variable name="radioName" select="Fields/Radio/*" />        
</myRadio>
```

Will this create `<input type="radio" etc/>` with radioName pointing to the data from `Fields/Radio/*` on `main.xsl` in my resulting jsp page after generation?

```
Error:
Warning: Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor
Warning: at xsl:variable on line 34 of file:/C:/allTemplates.xsl:
  SXWN9001: A variable with no following sibling instructions has no effect
Warning: Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor
Warning: Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor
Error on line 990 of file:/C:/fields.xsl (another random file):
  FORG0001: Failure converting untyped value "" to a number
```

Comment: First your variable is in a local scope of `<xsl:template match="myRadio">`. Second you cannot assign values to variables. Variables in XSL are more "constant" than "variable". You'll have to rethink your problem in order to store values in variables.